# Ubuntu 20.04 open windows cover search area

Tags: 20.04, gnome, activities-overview

I have a problem since I've added second monitor - when I press "windows" key and try to search, miniatures of open windows covers the search result - is there something I can do with that?

Comment: That sounds like a graphics issue, where the miniatures keep shining through. Edit your post and add specifications about your hardware, in particular the graphics card.

Comment: Some how, the next day, the problem fixed itself. I dont know what happened. That you for your involvement.